# how to show google that a video on my site is a duplicate

Tags: iframe, video, seo, duplicate-data, canonical-link

(newbie=me) On my wordpress website I have video1 and I want to put it in two places on the website because it makes sense from a users perspective.

Video1 is embeded using html5; its and seo embed from Wistia. I want to put copy_video1 on a different page with text that is also different and useful. The thumbnail/frame-of-video used for copy_video1 is different than video1 making it more relevant to its page.

I thought I would use an iframe for copy_video1 since I had read google doesn't index iframes?. I thought to go the extra mile and use best practices that I should use canonical in the iframe to point to video1. Is this correct? What does the syntax look like for an iframe and video with canonical in it?

Is this the same method I would use for the video if an external site wanted to embed my video?

I guess this is also and seo question, but mostly to code it correctly for indexing.

THis is for a small non-profit site...

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of many instances where you would have to duplicate a video on the same website, so my recommendation is to just have one and use HTML5's poster attribute.  You would just set it to a different image on the other page.  This should work, should replace your first line of the :

```
<video controls poster="/images/othervideo1.jpg">
```

Comment: The video is from a 3rd party site, wistia, so its brought in by iframe. I wanted to possibly use canonical on the copy so that is shows that its not the origonal and points back to video1. So, I'm looking for the syntax for an iframe and video with canonical in it?